# Can I use a string as delimiter while using boost split method?

Tags: c++, boost, split

I am trying to parse an HTML string using the split method from boost. Can it be used with a string delimiter like `"<td>"` ? Can someone give me an example of how to do it efficiently ?

I am trying to do something like

```
vector <string> fields;
split( fields, str,  is_any_of( "<td>" ) );
```

But then I understand that it is treating '<','t','d' and '>' - all characters as delims.I am trying to find a way to use a string as delim.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for `split` it works on a character-by-character basis, treating the string as a sequence of characters. Therefore the predicate it uses to determine if something is a delimiter can only test a single character, so if you want to split on a complete string you're going to need to use something else. A regular expression library would certainly be able to do it, but you could fairly easily hand-code one by searching for substrings.